# jquery pagination not work after ajax load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im use jspages.js to create pagination from jquery. everything is okay when page loaded at the first time. but i have error when the content on pagination loaded after ajax. the plugin dint work :(. this my code to create pagination.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jPages.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
            $("ul li img").lazyload({
                    event : "turnPage",
                effect : "fadeIn"
        });
        $(".holder").jPages({
            containerID : "itemContainer",
            animation   : "fadeInUp",
            previous    : "Prev",
            next        : "Next",
            perPage     : 3,
            callback    : function( pages, items ){
                items.showing.find("img").trigger("turnPage");
                items.oncoming.find("img").trigger("turnPage");
                }
            });
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Put your code after success from ajax

success: function(result) {
                 $(".holder").jPages({
            containerID : "itemContainer",
            animation   : "fadeInUp",
            previous    : "Prev",
            next        : "Next",
            perPage     : 3,
            callback    : function( pages, items ){
                items.showing.find("img").trigger("turnPage");
                items.oncoming.find("img").trigger("turnPage");
                }
            });

            },
```

Comment: thaks for the answer. two thumb